# Test speed (send and receive information) client (app) - database (server)

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, iis, cmd, windows-server-2008

I would like to test time connection (send and receive information) between client (app) - database (server MSSQL). For example I test lan speed using iperf but I don't know how test speed time between servers and which value will be correct (ask for sql send sql - time). Could you help me find something better then ping and iperf? :)

Comment: This question is more appropriate on http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iperf and I written UnitTest